# Is there a way to find a reverse iterator for the first element in a std::map less than a given key?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdmap, lower-bound

I came across the following code snippet in C++ (I am not yet on C++11):

```
int test(std::map<int, size_t> &threshold, const int value) {
  std::map<int, size_t>::const_iterator itr = threshold.upper_bound(value);

  if (threshold.begin() == itr) {
    return -1;
  }
  return return (--itr)->second;
}
```

In particular, I do not like the use of `--itr` at the end nor the compare of `itr` to `begin()`, they both feel wrong to me.

I'm wondering if there is a way with STL to do some kind of lookup that would return end() (or rend()) if not found and otherwise to return the last element that is less than or equal to the `value` so the code would look more like this:

```
int test(std::map<int, size_t> &threshold, const int value) {
  std::map<int, size_t>::const_reverse_iterator itr = threshold.WhatGoesHere(value);

  if (threshold.rend() == itr) {
    return -1;
  }
  return return itr->second;
}
```

In a sense, I want a reverse_lower_bound() that returns a reverse iterator to the last element that is not greater than the `value` or if none can be found rend().

Comment: I retract my comment, it'll not be the same. I'm currently working on an answer.

Comment: Even though you don't like the code you started with, it looks OK to me. There's nothing wrong with comparing an iterator to `begin()` and nothing wrong with decrementing it.

Comment: @Mark: Are you sure? IIRC, `lower_bound` returns equal or greater, while `upper_bound` returns strictly greater.

Comment: @Xeo, yup I messed up on that. Deleting my comment.

Comment: @Xeo It looked correct to me given that reversing an iterator gives you prior element.  Note I edited the last paragraph of question, it did not match the code's behavior.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Yeah, I'm always a bit confused by `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. Your answer is nearly right, it's just that iterators are not implicitly convertible to their reverse counterparts, you need to explicitly construct it (not using `=`).

Comment: @Xeo, I've edited it to explicitly call the constructor since that constructor is `explicit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Xeo's comment, I think this is the answer:

```
int test(std::map<int, size_t> &threshold, const int value) {
  std::map<int, size_t>::const_reverse_iterator
    last_element_not_greater_than(threshold.upper_bound(value));

  if (threshold.rend() == last_element_not_greater_than) {
    return -1;
  }
  return return last_element_not_greater_than->second;
}
```

I learned this new thing:

```
When an iterator is reversed, the reversed version does not point to the same
element in the range, but to the one preceding it.
```

Comment: I didn't know that about reverse iterators either. Citation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/